# Java what is wrong with this interface

Tags: java

What is wrong with the following interface? This is a test question where you have to find the error.

```
public interface SomethingIsWrong {
    void aMethod(int aValue) {
        System.out.println("Hi Mom");
    }
}
```

Comment: Put it in `SomethingIsWrong.java`, compile it, and see for yourself. This is not a place to go begging for test answers!

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8+ interfaces can provide default implementations, but they require the `default` keyword. Something like,

```
public interface SomethingIsWrong {
    default void aMethod(int aValue) {
        System.out.println("Hi Mom");
    }
}
```

Comment: Language lawyer.  I need to be doing more with JDK8.  I'l bet the professor is old school Java like me who's unaware of this change.

Answer (score 0):

Interface methods do not have implementations.

Comment: Java 8+ interfaces can have `default` implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Interface is a contract declaration. It can't contain implementation of the method

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces cannot have implementation code - check the Java Tutorial here for an explanation about how to implement interfaces in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html